# Getting an invalid type error during contract instantiation on the Archway network

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

When I try to instantiate the contract the following error is thrown:

> Error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = rpc error: code = Unknown desc
> = failed to execute message; message index: 0: Error parsing into type cw_arcade::msg::InstantiateMsg: Invalid type: instantiate wasm
> contract failed [CosmWasm/wasmd@v0.32.0/x/wasm/keeper/keeper.go:302]
> With gas wanted: '300000000' and gas used: '135732' : unknown request

The following is the structure of the instantiation message type:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug, PartialEq, JsonSchema)]
pub struct InstantiateMsg {
    pub admins: Vec<String>,
    pub name: String,
    pub max: u8,
    pub price: u128,
    pub denom: String,
}
```

The following is the data submitted from the frontend:

```
{
    "admins":
    [
        "archway1uwew6p8k70xa2lkzeujqcw430uky49zthsvc0y",
        "archway10mxcxvyjnpcmnkg0sxf7r25f3wzjqdz6jp4jux",
        "archway1a8dq0wced6q29rppdug7yvk8ek0dsrqwe3hxcz"
    ],
    "name": "Name",
    "max": 250,
    "price": 1000000000,
    "denom": "aconst"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price should be submitted as a **string** and not an **integer**.

To avoid compatibility issues across different platforms that can't support large integers, such as JavaScript, **Serde** requires **u128** values to be represented as strings for deserialization. Specifically, JavaScript's ability to represent integers without loss of precision is limited to the range -2^53 + 1 to 2^53 - 1 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_encoding), which is significantly smaller than the maximum range of the u128 type.